# How to create certificate for gitblit server?

Tags: ssl-certificate, gitblit, sslexception

I use a `gitblit` server.

I can access it using: `https://localhost:8443`, but when accessing `https://192.168.10.1:8443`, which is the IP address of my PC, I see `SSL Error`.

Can someone please shed a light on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certificates are tied to hostnames.

By default Gitblit GO generates a self-signed certificate for `localhost`.  If you access Gitblit GO over https using a different hostname (like the IP address) the browser will complain about the hostname mismatch.  It will also complain about the self-signed certificate even if you are accessing the server from the expected hostname.  Both of these are standard security responses.

Your solution choices are:

1. Add an exception for your self-signed cert
2. Initiate a CSR (certificate signing request) and purchase a signed certificate through a Certificate Authority (Thawte, VeriSign, etc).
3. Don't use https

Comment: Can I use Gitblit GO to generate certificate on my own?